# Removing empty page from a print form link (&IsDlg=1&printit=true)

Tags: form, hyperlink, printing

I can print a form using

https://thesite/Lists/Request/EditForm.aspx?ID=8305&IsDlg=1&printit=true

The problem is that this site sometimes has empty pages:
[image]

Is it possible to fix this issue? I wasn't able to find anything on the internet regarding this.

Thanks in advance!